# AWS API Gateway - Enable $input for CloudWatch Log

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, sensitive-data

I have a **REST API exposed in API Gateway** and those requests **have path params and query params**. I want to store some data from the request in CloudWatch.

In the settings I have checked the *Log full requests/responses data* option.

[image]

In the Custom Access Logging I have checked *Enable Access Logging*  and this `log format`:

```
{"requestId":"$context.requestId", "carId":"method.request.querystring.carId","color":"$input.params('color')"}
```

But in CloudWatch the result is:

```
{"requestId":"XXXXXX", "carId":"-","color":"-"}
```

Following the AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference%3Fcmpid=docs_apigateway_console

The request is: `https://test.domain.demo/v1/cars/123456/data?color=red`

Why I am getting a `-` instead of the correct value?

Comment: Only $context variables are supported (not $input, and so on) in Access logging.

reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html